# How do I send an image from my Android app and store it in a MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

How do I send an image from my Android app and store it in a MySQL database. 
and later fetch it in some other app and display the image?

Comment: show us your code what you have tried so far

Comment: Why are you store image in database? . instead of store image you can just save in Memorycard or default storage folder, and save that path in your sql database. For that use your image quality will not disturb.

Answer (score 1):

base64 is a way to save image. but you will get an error with image which have large size. the string is too long and you can't post it to server. The best way that i have is convert it to byte array, pass it to server, save it as an image on your host, and save the path to database.